# JTextField, Swing

Tags: java, swing

Пишу игру "Балда". Планирую создать 5х5, каждая ячейка - это отдельный JTextField. Игровой процесс: ход ирока_1 - вводит 1 букву, после чего блокируется ввод в оставшиеся JTextField, нажимая на отдельные ячейки выбирает слово, после чего игрок_2 допускает данное слово или нет и т.д.(см.скрин, внизу две кнопки).

Не знаю как сделать следующее: блокировка и разблокировка JTextField, и выборка конкретных букв для создания слова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Основной класс](https://github.com/Mazuruk-O/ProgSecongLab/blob/master/src/GUI/GameFieldGui.java); [Игровое поле(массив для хранения букв)](https://github.com/Mazuruk-O/ProgSecongLab/blob/master/src/log/entity/GameField.java); [Игрок](https://github.com/Mazuruk-O/ProgSecongLab/blob/master/src/log/entity/Player.java)

Comment: пробовал - `yourJTextField.setEditable(false)` ? (это для блокировки/разблокировки)

Comment: нет, сейчас попробую

Comment: да, спасибо, это решаем мою проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// создание текстового поля
JTextField jTextField_enter = new JTextField();
jTextField_enter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            // этот метод будет выполняться при вводе нового символа
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // запрет редактирования текстового поля
                jTextField_enter.setEditable(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
 });
```